# Primary Key id Reset after insert after delete Record

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have table name called TP_Projects i had set Id in Primary key. previous i have 25 Records after that  i delete  record  4 record to 25 Record .now going to insert  new value this new value id showing 26. how to set  this id to 4  ..

Comment: You reset it by truncating the table. (TRUNCATE TABLE TP_Projects)

Comment: @MK_ No, you don't. `Truncate table` will also delete all records from the table.

Comment: Why do you need that? Do not expect the identities to be consecutive and without gaps.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter - I was answering before the edit when the question sounded like that's what thenna wants to do (delete all records + reset the ID).

Answer (score 0):

This should start at the Identity you want.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (tablename, reseed,4)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can just truncate the table using below query if you don't have anything useful in the table and just dummy data:
TRUNCATE TABLE `TP_Projects`

Another way is :
ALTER TABLE `TP_Projects` AUTO_INCREMENT = 4

Comment: i used but  all data deleted i want first three data that also  deleted

Comment: This is sql server. You can't alter a column to re-seed identity, nor can you alter it to become and identity column (or to stop being an identity column).

Comment: Just use :  ALTER TABLE TP_Projects AUTO_INCREMENT = 4 .